# Order angular datatables without showing user interaction triangles

Tags: angular, datatables

I would like to have the data sorted in a fixed way, without the user interacting with the sorting. The issue is that it seems either possible to disable ordering completely, like this:

```
this.dtOptions = {
  paging: false,
  lengthChange: false,
  searching: false,
  ordering: false,           // <<< ordering set to false
  autoWidth: true,
  info: false,
  order: [[0, 'asc']]
```

Or to have it enabled, including the user interaction triangles at the header of the table, like this:

```
this.dtOptions = {
  paging: false,
  lengthChange: false,
  searching: false,      
  ordering: true,         // <<< ordering set to true
  autoWidth: true,
  info: false,
  order: [[0, 'asc']]
```

**Question**: How can I get the table sorted without showing the user interaction?

Comment: You want to sort it by a specific field of your data and then keep it that way without allowing the users to change anything?

Comment: @igg thank you for your reply! It seems simple: I want it sorted by column 0 but I do not want to show user interaction elements for sorting. But I cant get it to work.

Comment: Why don't you sort your data in your code before rendering it with datatables and then just set `ordering` to `false`?

Comment: @igg yes, that would be a work-around. I just did not expect this to be this difficult.

Comment: What are you having difficulty with?

Comment: @igg getting the little user-interaction triangles to not show. But its alright, I will do it like you suggested and just sort before handing the data to the datatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the answer by igg and sorted the data in the code before rendering datatables and then set ordering to false.